# Dynamically Adding Buttons in Android Program

Tags: java, android, multithreading, dynamic

I have the following code to dynamically add buttons for each item in the the toylist object toyCatalog, which is 46 items long.

```
   toyCatalog = new ToyList(content, length);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
        int numToys = toyCatalog.getNumOfToys();

        for(int i =0; i<numToys; i++){
            System.out.println("adding button " + i);
            Button myButton = new Button(this);
            myButton.setText("New Toy");
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
            ll.addView(myButton, lp);
        }
```

However, when I try to run the code, I get

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

And only three buttons show up on the page. How do I manage the work on the main thread so I can dynamically add buttons?

Comment: Your code for creating a button programatically is fine. Nothing wrong with it. As the logcat says, there seems to be a lot being done on your main thread. My I ask, where does this code snippet located on your application? Can you provide the whole code with the method or class it belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you are seeing may not be related to your code.  It's impossible to know for sure with the snippet you provided.  But there is one you can do to optimize it.

Find the parent view only once.  Move this code outside the loop and simply refer to ll inside it.  There is no reason to find the parent at every iteration:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

You can also void calling getNumOfToys at each iteration by storing it in a variable and using that in your for loop.  It looks like there is already a `length` value available, so maybe just use that instead.

Also verify for certain how many times this loop operates.  Too many iterations will certainly cause a problem.

Lastly, make sure your LinearLayout has a vertical orientation so the buttons are stacked on top of each other.  The default horizontal orientation will show only one button.

Comment: I edited the original question to reflect your changes, but still getting the same issue of skipped frames.

Comment: Like I said the code here may not be responsible for the message you're seeing.  It's impossible to know for sure.  The only way to know for sure is for you to run a profiler against the app and look for methods that are taking a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think its related and you always have to add views on the main thread so there isnt much you can do. What do the System.out.println show?